# How to search for items in an already generated ListView.builder with Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

At the moment, I am displaying a list of items received by the query and the database. How can I use the search bar to rebuild ListView.builder. I only use StatelessWidget since I'm trying to learn the getX package. How will my SearchBar link to the list of items?

Given that in the Search bar I need to join the onChanged property

P.S: I'm sorry for my English, it's terrible)

**My builder code:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<ProductController>(
      init: ProductController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<ProductsCombined>>(
          future: controller.productList.value,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    ProductCards(
                  index: index,
                  snapshot: snapshot,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**My controller code:**

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  final productList = Future.value(<ProductsCombined>[]).obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<List<ProductsCombined>> callDb() async {
    return await DBHelper.db.getProducts();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    productList.value = callDb();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:
I tried to do this, but without success**

Changed the controller code:

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  final productList = Future.value(<ProductsCombined>[]).obs;
  Rx<Future <List<ProductsCombined>>> filterProduct = Future.value(<ProductsCombined>[]).obs;//Переписать productList в копию и везде указывать уже копию

  Future<void> searchChanged(String value) async{
    if(value != null && value.isNotEmpty){
       List<ProductsCombined> s = await productList.value;
      filterProduct = Future.value(s.where((element) => (element.productName.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))).toList()).obs;
    }
    filterProduct = productList;
  }


  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchProducts();
    filterProduct = productList;
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<List<ProductsCombined>> callDb() async {
    return await DBHelper.db.getProducts();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    productList.value = callDb();
  }
}
```

Calling a method in TextField:

```
TextField(
        onChanged: (string) {
          controller.searchChanged(string);
        }
```

Also in FutureBuilder, I changed the controller.ProductList.value on the controller.filterProduct.value

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes, share the solution with us :D